# How to show motionlayout android studio design tool?

Tags: android-motionlayout

How to show tool design like that.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yc_Or1Xscad24fsg35pgN_FGbOwR0Z67/view?usp=sharing
In my android studio not show.

Comment: please describe what exactly do you need, what have you tried and how that failed

Answer (score 0):

The MotionEditor development has been temporarily put aside until after I/O because of Project Marble and optimisations in other Android Studio Design tools. Nicolas said in a tweet that they hope to have a preview out in a canary soon after I/O, no promises made though!

See https://twitter.com/camaelon/status/1116105852325437441.